# Polymorphism 1 Superclass 4 Subclass

Tags: java, polymorphism

Let's says I have 5 classes, 1 superclass and 4 subclasses. My superclass is `Animal` and has `Species` and `Charateristic`, these 2 will be inherited to my subclasses.

4 subclasses are: `Lion`, `Eagle`, `Bee`, and `Whale` ( these 4 subclasses extend `Animal` ). These subclasses will have methods `Voice()` and `Walk()`.

The question is, that my mentor told its student:

**case 1.** If this program is running it is launched, there will be a menu that shows that 4 subclasses / `Animal` objects.

**case 2.** After the user has chosen an animal, for example: `Eagle`. Then it shows what voice and movement an eagle has.

**case 3.** If the user chooses exit, then terminate the program.

In this case, we will use `switch + case`, right? But then my question is how do I call these 4 subclasses from my superclass?

If I add `public static void main` inside each of the subclasses, then these 4 subclasses become a `main` method, and I'm unable to set or create it with `switch` case. Or do I have to create another class that extends those 4 subclasses and call it?

Thank you, I hope you've understood what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

You should access the subclass methods through virtual method calls (on a reference typed to the superclass). You can use Factory design pattern as well. Can be something like this:

```
int choice;
// read the choice, if exit chosen then exit

// getAnimal returns the actual animal instance
// (either a new instance or an existing one from internal registry)
// can select by switch() inside
Animal *animal = getAnimal(choice); // or Animal::getAnimal(choice), etc.

if (animal == null) {
    System.err.println("Invalid choice");
} else {
    // will call the methods on the actual specific animal retrieved by getAnimal()
    animal.Voice();
    animal.Walk();
}
```

Neither Animal nor the animal kinds should have main() - only the actual application which handles the entire logic (that could be the Animal class as well, but maybe better to create a separate class for the application itself).

**EDIT:** This is how the `getAnimal()` method could look like:

```
Animal * getAnimal(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        return new Lion();
    case 2:
        return new Eagle();
    // etc.
    default:
        // invalid choice
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So i don't need to create 4 subclasses is that it what you suggest ? 
But my mentor give me an image for this task that there are 4 subclasses extends the Animal. 

And i should create a separate class for the main() application itself ? such an example that is given by shnplr ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to implement the subclasses (which will each implement the `Voice()` and `Walk()` methods appropriately). And in my example, the `getAnimal()` should retrieve the appropriate instance according to the selection. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

At some point you have to create your animal instances

```
Animal a1 = new Lion();
Animal a2 = new Eagle();
System.out.println(a1.Species());
System.out.println(a2.Species());
```

Create a separate class to control your program containing main e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opt = 1; // TODO - use args
    switch (opt) {
      case 1: 
        Lion obj = new Lion();
        System.out.println("Voice: " + obj.Voice() + ", Walk: " + obj.Walk();
        break;
      case 2:
        Eagle obj = new Eagle();
        System.out.println("Voice: " + obj.Voice() + ", Walk: " + obj.Walk();
        break;
 // etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond :))  , where do i create my animal instances ? inside my Animal class ?

and that class MyClass, a seperate class to control my program containing the main() ? so i have another sub class besides those 4 ? 

Thank you

Comment: The application class (`MyClass` here) does not need to be subclass of `Animal`. This can be entirely unrelated class (except that it will import and use the animal classes to provide the functionality).